# This Expression causes side effect and will not be evaluated

Tags: c#, linq, debugging

I am getting this error on my LINQ query and i am not for sure why. when i run the table is empty but when i add a break point a force the results then it works find and adds all the data in perfectly

```
    private void GetSQLOraclelinqData()
    {

        var TstarData = GetTrackstarTruckData();
        var M5Data = GetM5Data();

        DataTable ComTable = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataColumn OraColumn in M5Data.Columns)
        {
            ComTable.Columns.Add(OraColumn.ColumnName, OraColumn.DataType); 

        }
        foreach (DataColumn SQLColumn in TstarData.Columns)
        {
            if (SQLColumn.ColumnName == "VehicleName")
                ComTable.Columns.Add(SQLColumn.ColumnName + 2, SQLColumn.DataType);
            else
                ComTable.Columns.Add(SQLColumn.ColumnName, SQLColumn.DataType);

        }

        var results = TstarData.AsEnumerable().Join(M5Data.AsEnumerable(),
            a => a.Field<String>("VehicleName"),
            b => b.Field<String>("Unit_NO"),
                (a, b) =>
                {

                    DataRow row = ComTable.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = a.ItemArray.Concat(b.ItemArray).ToArray();
                    ComTable.Rows.Add(row);
                    return row;

                });

        SQLDataTable.ItemsSource = ComTable.DefaultView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ToList like this:

```
var results = TstarData.AsEnumerable().Join(M5Data.AsEnumerable(),
            a => a.Field<String>("VehicleName"),
            b => b.Field<String>("Unit_NO"),
                (a, b) =>
                {

                    DataRow row = ComTable.NewRow();
                    row.ItemArray = a.ItemArray.Concat(b.ItemArray).ToArray();
                    ComTable.Rows.Add(row);
                    return row;

                }).ToList();
```

Comment: It worked thank you how do I close this and give you credit. this only my second day on here